# Secondary-only nodes in mongodb Replica set

Tags: java, mongodb, distributed-system

I am working on a project where I want to have the ability to specify that certain nodes of the replica set can never be primary nodes ie in case of a failure where all primary capable nodes die the system should be reduced to a read-only state till some primary capable node comes up. Is this possible? If yes how? If not what is the best way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [the documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Configuration#ReplicaSetConfiguration-TheReplicaSetConfigObject) (emphasis mine):

> `priority` - priority a server has for potential election as primary. The highest priority member which is up will become primary. Default 1.0. **Priority zero means server can never be primary**.

So setting the priority to zero should achieve what you want.

Comment: Can I run queries against priority zero node? If yes how?

Comment: @Ankur Chauhan: Sure, just connect to the node and query it. If it gives you a "not master" error, call `rs.slaveOk()` to allow queries on slave nodes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, mongodb does not *completely* support what you require yet. If you restart a read-only slave while there is no primary, it will enter STARTUP2 state, not SECONDARY. Trying to query a mongod instance while in STARTUP2 will fail.

So if you had a unrobust setup, e.g. your cluster of masters and cluster of read only servers in the same city and there was a power cut, and you end up with the primary DC down (someone forgot to check the generators & UPS) and the read only servers came back up fine (generator in other DC works fine) then you will be in a situation where the slaves will not work.